# jquery mobile pagecontent beforeshow not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this checkbox that when it's checked, it should add some text/content to a favourites page. I've trying to find a way to make it happen, but no luck so far.
I've been trying to go around this code:
Javascript:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.toPage.is('#favs')){
        if($('#event1Fav').is(":checked")){
            $('#favs#favList').append('<br /><a href="#eventDesc1">Event 1</a><br />');
            } else{
                $('#favs-content').append("");
            }
    }
    } );
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="event1Fav"/>Add to Favourites
```

Any help would be very much appretiated :)

Comment: event1Fav is in favs page? And what's fav!ist? You can't have two IDs for same page.

Comment: event1Fav is in a different page,  favList is th id of the content data-role of the favs page. what I want to do is to add a link to the favs page that directs the user to the checked page. Thank you for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you have checkbox in a different page, you have to specify in which page it is. That's in case you have the same checkbox in different pages with same ID.

Moreover, `#favs#favList` is a wrong selector, you should leave a space between them. Or find it within target page `$("#favList", ui.toPage)` or `ui.toPage.find("#favList")`.

Javascript:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.toPage.is('#favs')){
        if($('#pageID #event1Fav').is(":checked")){
            $('#favList', ui.toPage).append('<br /><a href="#eventDesc1">Event 1</a><br />');
        } else {
            $('#favs-content', ui.toPage).append("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much for your help and quick reply